# How can i install Python3 in NAO V6 (embedded)?

Tags: nao-robot

Is possible install Python3 in NAO V6? I try install but don’t have emerge and the root only can read.

I’m search in the internet alternatives but i don’t found something about this.

Comment: The new NAOqi version for NAO V6 (2.8.6), which can be downloaded from the Aldebaran Cloud website, now comes with Python3. Is it possible for you to upgrade the OS version? Otherwise I can detail the process but it's quite complicated and requires setting up a virtual machine, compiling code on that, then copying it to NAO.

Answer (score 0):

NAOqi 2.8.6 includes Python 3.
For older versions, you will need to compile Python with NAO's toolchain.
Since NAO's toolchain uses CMake, you should [build Python with CMake too](https://github.com/python-cmake-buildsystem/python-cmake-buildsystem).
You can bring the compiled binaries along with the program you want to run on NAO.